# WordPress display post by day

Tags: php, wordpress

I am running a music website, and currently on my index page I have it filtering the latest content by "**Category**", how ever I am wondering how I can make it filter by post per day.

I am assuming I would need to have some custom work done within my `functions.php` file as appose to the default mock up I am running currently, here's my current code.

```
<div class="list">
<h4 style="padding-left: 4px; ">Latest Singles.</h4>
<?php query_posts('posts_per_page=10&cat=2'); if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();?> 
<div class="item">
<div class="artwork">
<?php the_post_thumbnail('artwork'); ?>
</div>
<div class="meta">
<strong><a style="color: #777777; text-decoration: none;" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></strong> <br>
<em><?php echo get_the_date(); ?> <?php the_tags(); ?> </em> <br>
<a rel="nofollow" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Download</a>
</div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Any suggestions is much appreciated.

Comment: Does that mean you want the index to display only the posts from one day?

Comment: You should never ever use `query_posts`, neither should you replace the main query with a custom one. Use `pre_get_posts` to alter the main query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should never use `query_posts`, it breaks the main query object and pagination. As this should be the main query, you should use `pre_get_posts` to alter the main query. You should never replace the main query with a custom one, except on page templates.

This goes into functions.php

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $q )
{ 

    if ( $q->is_home() && $q->is_main_query() ) {
        $q->set(  'posts_per_page', 10 );
        $q->set( 'cat', 2 );
        $date_query = array(
            array(
                'year'  => $today['year'],
                'month' => $today['mon'],
                'day'   => $today['mday'],
            ),
         );
         $q->set( 'date_query', $date_query );
    }

});
```

It should be noted that your index.php should be looking like this, no custom query, no nothing, just the normal default loop

```
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();

        // Rest of your HTML mark up and loop elements

    }
}
```

Comment: Never ever use `query_posts`. It breaks the main query object and page functionalities

Comment: If so than, WordPress could deprecate that function but they didn't !

Comment: They can't as that will break millions of sites. Ignorance is the biggest problem here as no one of those millions care to read the codex which I believe you also haven't done. And one note, you should also not replace the main query witha custom one, you should be using the build in filter action `pre_get_posts` to adjust the main query to your needs

Comment: Could you show me another example of this with the code I have given? What Pieter is saying is really confusing me..

Comment: @Lee I just wanted to write a simple answer for this simple thing to do, Pieter said a standard way of calling Action hook pre_get_posts which is also good practice. But my answer will also work here.

Comment: @PieterGoosen could you please write my given code using pre_get_posts action to get the desired result?

Comment: I have updated your post. Hope that makes sense. I haven't tested it though, but should work if there are no bugs :-). You can roll back my changes if you are not happy with it. Good luck :-)

Comment: @PieterGoosen thank you so much also thank you Abdoon

Comment: @Lee my pleasure. Glad it worked. You should take your time and read up on `pre_get_posts` and how to modify the main query to fit your needs. Enjoy :-)